# CSS Layout Problems (with pictures and code) in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I was wondering if anyone could help me troubleshoot some CSS issues I'm running into with the dreaded IE.  Here's the undesired layout as rendered by IE...

[alt text http://beeeph.squarespace.com/storage/images/misc/ielayout.jpg](http://beeeph.squarespace.com/storage/images/misc/ielayout.jpg)

and here's the correct layout (as rendered by Firefox and Chrome)...

[alt text http://beeeph.squarespace.com/storage/images/misc/correctlayout.jpg](http://beeeph.squarespace.com/storage/images/misc/correctlayout.jpg)

you can see there are three undesired differences in IE...

1. The left tabs (`#header-tabs`) get all bunched up in the upper right hand corner of the page
2. The main logo, paragraph, and image (`#header-container`) get indented too far to the right
3. The login box and button are misaligned

[alt text http://beeeph.squarespace.com/storage/images/misc/ielayoutdifferences.jpg](http://beeeph.squarespace.com/storage/images/misc/ielayoutdifferences.jpg)

I've read through a few different tutorials on fixing the most common IE problems, such as the float/double-margin problem and the width/padding box problem, but that didn't change anything.

Here's my CSS code...

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* my styles */

body {
    /*margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;*/
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:100%;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:62.5%;
    /*line-height:185%;*/
}

#header-navbar {
    background:#000000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    border-top:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    width:100%;
}

#header-toplinks {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height:50px;
    padding-left:44px;  
}

#header-toplinks a{
    border-bottom:1px solid #38373A;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#header-toplinks a:hover{
    color:#9E9B9B;
}

#header-toplinks ul, li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}

#header-login {
    float:right;
    height:12px;
    padding:3px 5px 0px 0px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:left;
}

.form-search .text {
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height:18px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100px;
    color:#AAAAAA;
}

.form-search .search-button {
    background:#999999;
    border:medium none;
    font-size:1em;
    height:18px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    margin-left:-2px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:52px;
}

#header-tab_projects{
    float:left;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:105px;
    z-index:50;
}
#header-tab_blog{
    float:left;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:275px;
    z-index:50;
}

#header-container {
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-left:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#header-container p {
    color:#AAAAAA;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:1.3em;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    width:500px;    
}

.portrait img {
background:#EFEFEF none repeat scroll 0 0;
border:1px solid #EEEEEE;
margin-bottom:5px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
}

#footer {
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:100px;
    width:100%;
}
```

*Update:  When I removed `position: fixed` and replaced it with `position: absolute`, it fixed problems #1 and #2 :)

Comment: Your CSS ended up being a bit of a mess, and there's no HTML.. so it would still be rather difficult for someone to figure this out for you. Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: What a surprise, CSS problems with IE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it ie6 specific or all ie versions?
Note ie6 & early ie7 versions do not understand position fixed...[more](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html)

Comment: thank you, i'll look into this.  any recommendations for replacing position fixed with something that will have the same effect in IE?

Comment: I guess you're stuck with using javascript, if you want to keep certain text on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It may be silly to ask but does your HTML validate? What about your CSS? I have often found that when experiencing weird or unexpected behavior in different browsers that it is because I am doing something invalid in HTML/CSS. It may not be your problem but it is probably worth a quick check

Comment: ... or no doctype is declared

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

1) To correct the alignment of the login box.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header-navbar">
 <div id="header-login">login content goes here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header-navbar {
background:#000000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
border-top:2px solid #FFFFFF;
width:100%;
position:relative;
}

#header-login {
position:absolute;
height:12px;
top:3px;
right:5px;
text-align:left;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

2) To place the buttons exactly on left side of the page

After ending the header part of the layout. Introduce a new container name the id as #main_content{}

write the below codes.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main_content">
 <div id="tab_projects">insert the project tab image</div>
 <div id="tab_blog">insert the blog tab image</div>
 <div id="content">some content goes here</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main_content{
position:relative;
text-align:left;
}

#content{
padding:0 0 0 50px;
}

#tab_projects{
position:absolute;
top:10px; /* adjust the top position according to your design */
left:0px;
}

#tab_blog{
position:absolute;
top:50px; /* adjust the top position according to your design */
left:0px;
}
```

I think this works... Just try it out.